# GUI File Picker

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, openfiledialog

I am trying to use PYQT5 file picker, but there is something I am missing. I'm having two problems. the first is when the file dialog box opens and I choose a file. the whole program crashed and I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'` and `QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting` that show in the terminal. The second is when I hit cancel on the file dialog the whole program crashes and it says `nboundLocalError: local variable 'newdata' referenced before assignment` and `QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting`. What I would like is to be able to have the dialog pop up and choose the file and then and then have the contents of that file be loaded into that variable. I'm not sure what is going wrong. I have posted my current code below. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

```
def open(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    try:
        fileToOpen = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,"Open File", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
    except:
        pass

    pdb.set_trace()
    if fileToOpen:
        with ZipFile(fileToOpen, 'r') as myzip:
            json_data_read = myzip.read('digest.json')
            newdata = json.loads(json_data_read)

    Functions.Loads = newdata[1]
```

Comment: Consider [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), else it's quite hard to help you.

Comment: Please don't use `except` without the specific exception(s) you are expecting and don't just essentially ignore the exception. In the code shown an exception (not) handled this way just leads to a follow up exception because `fileToOpen` is not defined.  Which leads to an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @BlackJack, Thank you for explaining that. I actually ran into that error and have fixed it since this post. I appreciate the comment as I am always trying to better my coding practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOpenFilename` returns a tuple. You want the second return value so call it like

```
fileToOpen, _ = getOpenFilename(...)
```

It's because pyqt5 calls getOpenFilenameAndFilter:  http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#qfiledialog

The second problem is because you don't init `newData` if there is no filename.

Comment: Perfect I just wrapped it in a `try` statement and it fixed the problem. Thank you for your advice